# My database won't add a value. I have code

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Is there something wrong with my code? setStatus always returns -1. Been tracing the code for errors but I can't find it. Maybe you guys here can. Very frustrating.

This is how I called the database:

```
SQLDatabaseLevelOne sql;

        sql = new SQLDatabaseLevelOne(MainActivity.this);
        sql.open();
        sql.setStatus("1");
        sql.close();
```

This is from my SQLDatabaseLevelOne.class:

```
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_QUESTION_STATUS = "_STATUS";
    public static final String KEY_SCORE = "_SCORE";
    //public static final String KEY_INDEX = "_INDEX";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "passworddb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "passwordtable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    //private int index_score;

    private DbHelper dbHelper;
    private final Context dbContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
            /*database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_QUESTION_STATUS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_SCORE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_INDEX + " TEXT NOT NULL);");*/
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_QUESTION_STATUS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_SCORE + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int arg1, int arg2) {
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(database);
        }
    }

        public SQLDatabaseLevelOne(Context context) {
            dbContext = context;
        }

        public long setStatus (String status) {         
            ContentValues dbContentValues = new ContentValues();
            dbContentValues.put(KEY_QUESTION_STATUS, status);
            //dbContentValues.put(KEY_SCORE, score);
            return sqlDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, dbContentValues);
        }

public void open() {
            dbHelper = new DbHelper(dbContext);
            sqlDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return;
        }

        public void close() {
            dbHelper.close();
        }
```

Comment: because `KEY_SCORE TEXT NOT NULL` has a constraint (NOT NULL) that is not satisfied, since you don't give it a value.

Comment: I don't know how to thank everyone. All of the replies are correct. I accepted the answers. I have been using NOT NULL without thinking the effects on the database.

Comment: It's ok, we all have more than enough points. Simply "pay it forward" someday in the future by helping someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted any LogCat errors, so there may be other problems as well. But you must set a value for *both* `KEY_QUESTION_STATUS` and `KEY_SCORE` since you specified that they cannot be `null` in the table's definition:

```
KEY_QUESTION_STATUS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
KEY_SCORE + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

---

What happens when you try this?

```
public long setStatus (String status) {         
    ContentValues dbContentValues = new ContentValues();
    dbContentValues.put(KEY_QUESTION_STATUS, status);
    dbContentValues.put(KEY_SCORE, "something");
    return sqlDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, dbContentValues);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your Table Create Query as

```
  database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_QUESTION_STATUS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_SCORE + " TEXT);");
```

because you are creating `KEY_SCORE`  as `TEXT NOT NULL` then u must pass value for  `KEY_SCORE` column

**NOTE :** after Changing Table structure you will need to change DB version

Comment: (+1) Hey ρяσѕρєя K, looks like you'll have more points than me in a couple weeks!

Answer (score 1):

In `setStatus()`, the call to `sqlDatabase.insert()` is returning `-1`. This means that your data is failing to be inserted.

Try changing it to `sqlDatabase.insertOrThrow()` instead; this will throw an exception on failure, which will make it much easier to find out what actually went wrong.

Comment: He has `not null` columns and his insert misses these columns -> failed insert.

Comment: Yep, I've upvoted the other answers which correctly diagnosed the actual problem.